# Built AOSP for Pixel 3a XL, after flashing device is not booting. No valid slot to boot

Tags: android-source

I am trying to build Pixel 3a XL AOSP for bonito. Downloaded vendor binaries from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/google_devices-bonito-sq1a.211205.008-c1845445.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/qcom-bonito-sq1a.211205.008-80e13c89.tgz

Build is successful. But after flashing device is stucked at google logo. Not betting at all.
No valid slot to boot!!!!!
Please Gide me whats wrong here?

Device should start correctly..

Comment: You need to provide more details on this, what tag did you sync. Additionally, your device needs to be a suitable version on both the slots.